# GROMACS Coordinates and velocity and force trajectories do not match accuracy

Tags: simulated-data, gromacs

I am using GROMACS to perform MD simulations of proteins. So, I tried to record the simulation results `nstxout`, `nstvout`, and `nstfout` with the same step size (`nstxout 1, nstvout 1, nstfout 1`). Then, I calculated the coordinate (step n) of an arbitrary step of the trajectory (step n) from the velocity of step n - 1, step n, and calculated the velocity of n - 1/2, and used that velocity to calculate the coordinate (n-1) of step n using the velocity of n - 1/2. LeapFrog was used in the simulation.

How can I get the coordinates, velocity, and force to be consistent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From GROMACS documentation about [reproducibility](https://manual.gromacs.org/current/user-guide/managing-simulations.html#reproducibility):

> The following factors affect the reproducibility of a simulation, and
> thus its output:
>
> - Precision (mixed / double) with double giving “better” reproducibility.
>   Number of cores, due to different order in which forces are accumulated. For instance (a+b)+c is not necessarily binary identical
>   to a+(b+c) in floating-point arithmetic.
> - Type of processors. Even within the same processor family there can be slight differences.
> - Optimization level when compiling.
> - Optimizations at run time: e.g. the FFTW library that is typically used for fast Fourier transforms determines at startup which version
>   of their algorithms is fastest, and uses that for the remainder of the
>   calculations. Since the speed estimate is not deterministic, the
>   results may vary from run to run.
> - Dynamic linking to different versions of shared libraries (e.g. for FFTs)
> - Dynamic load balancing, since particles are redistributed to processors based on elapsed wallclock time, which will lead to (a+b)+c
>   != a+(b+c) issues as above
> - Number of PME-only ranks (for parallel PME simulations)
> - MPI reductions typically do not guarantee the order of the operations, and so the absence of associativity for floating-point
>   arithmetic means the result of a reduction depends on the order
>   actually chosen
> - On GPUs, the reduction of e.g. non-bonded forces has a non-deterministic summation order, so any fast implementation is
>   non-reprodudible by design.

I would add that in your case of hard coding everything by hand you may have to look a bit into your barostat and thermostat (although their influence should be found on speed of the atoms). Maybe a sample code with coordinates and speed of 4 atoms would help to give a more precise answer.

You can also try having a look at [gromacs source code](https://github.com/gromacs/gromacs). I believe [OpenMM](https://github.com/openmm/openmm) provides a bit more control and clarity on each step, if for some unfathomable reason you are not doing this only for curiosity sake but because you actually have to make a code that reproduces these results.